# How to transform the nested array of objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I have an array of Object that I want to transform. It contains nested object structure as below :

```
 [
      {
        geography: 'Austia',
        product: 'RTD Coffee',
        dataType: 'Off-Trade rsp (curr/con, local)',
        timeSeries: [
          {
            year: 2017,
            value: 0.148891823777856,
            highlight: 1,
          },
          {
            year: 2018,
            value: 0.148965642232877,
            highlight: 1,
          },
          {
            year: 2019,
            value: 0.149039460687898,
            highlight: 1,
          },
          {
            year: 2020,
            value: 0.149113279142919,
            highlight: 1,
          },
          {
            year: 2021,
            value: 0.149187097597941,
            highlight: 1,
          },
          {
            year: 2022,
            value: 0.149260916052962,
            highlight: 1,
          },
        ],
      },...
    ];
```

I want to transform it to the below pattern where the TimeSeries array objects property are extracted and mapped top level as shown below:

```
[
  {
    geography: 'Austria',
    product: 'RTD Coffee',
    dataType: 'Off-Trade rsp (curr/con, local)',
    2017: 0.148891823777856,
    2018: 0.148965642232877,
    2019: 0.149039460687898,
    2020: 0.149113279142919,
    2021: 0.149187097597941,
    2022: 0.149260916052962,
  },
]
```

How do I do it?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I tried to use flatMap to flatten the json, but it didn't seem to work.

Comment: It's clearly not about flatting because you use one value for a key of the new object and the other for the value

Comment: You don't want `flatMap` here, you don't have nested arrays. You want to convert an array to an object. You can look up `reduce` or `Object.fromEntries` to produce that obect. As for the outer array, `map` is enough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

**EDIT**: thanks @geoffrey

```
function extractYearValue(arr) {
  return arr.map(({timeSeries, ...element}) => {
    const objYearValue = timeSeries.reduce((acc, curr) => {
        acc[curr.year] = curr.value
        return acc
    }, {})
    return {...element, ...objYearValue}
  })
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you please also tell me how it is done? I am very new to JavaScript. I would love to understand more.

Comment: spreading objects like that is extremely wasteful. `element` is created at each iteration, so mutating it would not mutate the input and the surrounding function would remain pure. It should be `timeSeries.reduce((acc, curr) => { acc[curr.year] = curr.value; return acc; }, element)`.

Comment: @Purushottam.Prasad you should ask this kind of question in a forum or in a chatroom. Stack Overflow aims to be a knowledge base, which is why someone downvoted your question.